# One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is running. (winadows LocalHost wampserver)

Tags: magento2, cron, localhost

please help, i am using WAMP server 3 on windows and i have installed Magento 2.
but i am getting the following issue.

> One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is
>   running.

what is the solution for this one

and thanks
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Magento allows indexing by cron and command line interface

If cron is setup in your server magento will automatically indexing all data but in your local environment cron will not work, so you need to manually run the indexing command from CMD

Use following command to run reindexing

```
'Magento root'/bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

It will reindex all the indexers but make sure php command must be set in global environment

Answer (score 0):

change directory to magento root directory

```
$ cd <magento-root-folder>
```

after that run below command

```
bin\magento indexer:reindex
```

it will solve your problem

for more details, visit the below link

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-index.html

**CronJobs:**

Cron Jobs is a sheduled activities, it will automatically run every particular time interval. You can also able to run by commandline.

Run cron Jobs by command line

```
$ magento cron:run
```

for more details visit the below link

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the following steps worked for me:

1. Open Windows PowerShell.
2. Navigate to PHP folder: *change directories below based on your folder names.

---

```
cd c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.25
```

3. Run the following command: *replace xxxxx with your root directory name.

---

```
.\php c:\wamp\www\xxxxx\bin\magento indexer:reindex
```

4. You'll see indexing process work, Get some rest.